# How to order columns of a specific row in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['W', 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 'y'], ['e', 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 'H'], ['r', 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 'r']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']) 

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  W  4  2  1  3  5  y
1  e  2  3  4  5  1  H
2  r  3  2  5  4  1  r
```

And we want to order like this:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  W  1  2  3  4  5  y
1  e  1  2  3  4  5  H
2  r  1  2  3  4  5  r
```

Only sorting columns from 'b' to 'f', and keeping columns 'a' and 'g' at the same place.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo do que você tentou Leandro de Oliveira. Vi seu post no grupo do face e sei que não é isso, mas a impressão que passa é que você tá querendo uma resposta pronta por não ter colocado como vc tentou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `np.sort`

```
df.loc[:,'b':'f']=np.sort(df.loc[:,'b':'f'].values,1)
df
Out[161]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  W  1  2  3  4  5  y
1  e  1  2  3  4  5  H
2  r  1  2  3  4  5  r
```